# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android

Got this error when trying to run the app in Nexus 5x.

Below is the stack:

```
04-16 22:41:37.083 23199-23199/au.com... E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: au.com.beewest.natswarehouse, PID: 23199
                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{au.com.beewest.natswarehouse/au.com....MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276)
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
                                                                              at au.com.beewest.natswarehouse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                           Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:776)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                              at au.com.beewest.natswarehouse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/au.com.beewest.natswarehouse-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/au.com.beewest.natswarehouse-2/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                              at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:583)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:276) 
                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
                                                                              at au.com.beewest.natswarehouse.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26) 
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251) 
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                                                              at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                              at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                    ... 22 more
                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

And my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "au.com...."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
}
```

Comment: add your java and xml code too

Comment: Missing Design Support library and you should add  `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'` to build.gradle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'` to `build.gradle` to resolve

```
dependencies {
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
   compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
   compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
}
```

remember to change 23.2.1 to the build version you are using

Comment: Thanks man, Don't know how this line was missing in my "app-level" gradle.

Comment: What is build version ? how can i check which build version i'm using ?

Comment: how to find this dependency for androidx

Answer (score 1):

After digging around, I found **jetifier**.

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetify
npx cap sync android
```

> use jetifier for patching plugins that have not been updated to AndroidX

From [@jcesarmobile](https://github.com/jcesarmobile) on this github [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2810#issuecomment-617709664).