# Android app crashes directly after launch

Tags: android

My android app crashes after building and launching it with Android Studio on my phone. I see the splash screen for a second and then it stops. Saying the app 'suddenly stopped working'. I don't know what to do.

The ErrorMessage I get is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.name.app, PID: 18347
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.name.app/com.name.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.name.app:layout/bridge_layout_main: Binary XML file line #2 in com.name.app:layout/bridge_layout_main: Error inflating class androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3385)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3524)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2131)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7707)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.name.app:layout/bridge_layout_main: Binary XML file line #2 in com.name.app:layout/bridge_layout_main: Error inflating class androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2 in com.name.app:layout/bridge_layout_main: Error inflating class androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:454)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:815)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:659)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity.init(BridgeActivity.java:54)
    at com.name.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7825)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7814)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3360)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3524)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2131)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7707)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950) E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.name.app-_8ovKXIaSfDchcp1sairaw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.name.app-_8ovKXIaSfDchcp1sairaw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.name.app-_8ovKXIaSfDchcp1sairaw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /product/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        ... 27 more
```

Comment: Check this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36665619/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-2-binary-xml-file-line-2

Comment: You should add `com.name.app:layout/bridge_layout_main`.

Comment: There is an issue in your XML. You have a missing file or missing element in layout/bridge_layout_main

Answer (score 1):

[Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout and ClassNotFoundException: android.support.design.R$styleable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838594/error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-coordinatorlayout-and-classn)

Add into `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:latest.version.here'
```

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was **jetifier**.

```
npm install jetifier
npx jetify
npx cap sync android
```

> use jetifier for patching plugins that have not been updated to AndroidX

From [@jcesarmobile](https://github.com/jcesarmobile) on this github [issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/2810#issuecomment-617709664).